# Creating XLL without external libraries

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I have Office Excel add-in project and it's working, but it generates only DLL files, not XLL. Is there any possibility to create XLL file using only Visual Studio without using external libraries (ex. Excel-DNA)?

Comment: If you're dead set on using vanilla VS, then there's a Microsoft Docs page on making XLLs from scratch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/creating-xlls

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't want to use Excel-DNA? It's completely free and open source for all use, I made it exactly for this purpose (making XLLs with C#), and it's very widely used.